# To which Knapsack-problem variation does this problem correspond?

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

### Let us imagine that I have to fill my knapsack with items under constraints:

- Each item has an associated weight wi and profit pi
- With a maximum total weight Wmax

### Knowing that:

- There are categories of items and I have to choose **exactly one item** from each category
- Of course, the aim is to choose items to **maximise the sum of the profits**

### Example : Wmax=400

| Books | Books weights | Books profits | Food | Food weights | Food profits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| The Bible | 500 | 25 | Cheese | 80 | 120 |
| The little prince | 150 | 5 | Banana | 250 | 200 |

Here, the best solution  is (The little prince, Banana)

**I have a similar problem and I'd like to find out the best way to code it but I can't figure out what version/ variation of the probleme this is, is it a known variation ?**

Comment: it seems like the usual knapsack, where the volume of the sack is instead replaced by the maximum weight the sack can carry

Comment: So categories are usually included in the "classic" knapsack? In the wikipedia page, the classic variation is described as finding the optimal solution in a single category of items.

Comment: I left out this aspect, but the given answer addresses this variation via simple altération of the classical algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure if there’s an existing variation that matches yours, but it’s easy to draw inference from the classical variant and solve this.

Classic variant has 2D dynamic programming (`DP[N][W]`, where `N` and `W` are number of items and max weight).

In this variant, since we can only pick one of each category, you can use 3D DP like `dp[i][w][j]`, which denotes the maximum value you can get from the first `i` items with weight `w` and `j` is a 0/1 int denoting whether an item from category number `j` has been selected or not.

I’ll leave the implementation, since the recursive relation is relatively simple and quite similar to the classic variant.

Comment: Thank you sir ! I am not familiar with dynamic programming and the associated jargon (2D/3D DP). I will try to implement it and will add the code here when its done